# Merge elements in list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists like this:

```
A = [('b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a')]
```

How can I merge the all elements of each inner list to get result  `A = ['baaaa', 'baaaa']`? 
I would prefer to do this outside of a loop, if possible, to speed up the code.

Comment: You can never have `A = [baaaa, baaaa]` but you can have `A = ['baaaa', 'baaaa']`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to write a loop you can use [**`map`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [**`str.join`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
>>> list(map(''.join, A))
['baaaa', 'baaaa']
```

However, the loop using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is almost as short to write, and I think is clearer:

```
>>> [''.join(e) for e in A]
['baaaa', 'baaaa']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> ["".join(t) for t in A]
['baaaa', 'baaaa']
>>>
>>>
>>> list(map(''.join, A)        #with map
['baaaa', 'baaaa']
>>>
>>> help(str.join)
Help on method_descriptor:

join(...)
    S.join(iterable) -> str

    Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the
    iterable.  The separator between elements is S.

>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the join method of the empty string. This means: "make a string concatenating every element of a tuple (for example `('b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a')` ) with `''` (empty string) between each of them.

Thus, what you are looking for is:

```
 [''.join(x) for x in A]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer functional programming. You can use the function **reduce**. Here is how you can achieve the same result using reduce function as follows.

> Note that, reduce was a built in function in python 2.7 but in python
>   3 it is moved to library functools

```
from functools import reduce
```

It is only required to import reduce if you are using python 3 else no need to import reduce from functools

```
A = [('b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a')]
result = [reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, i) for i in A]
```

If you don't want to use loop or even list comprehension, here is another way

```
 list(map(lambda i: reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, i), A))
```